# Translate "High / Low Church" to German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I have come across the usage of "high church" and "low church" in a context pertaining to England, as categorizing someone's religious outlook. How would one best translate this to German, recreating the connotations rather than the literal meaning?

I understand that due to the somewhat isolated nature of Britain and quirks of history, the Anglican Church(es?) occupy a somewhat unique situation in the European spectrum.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_church) tells me:

> "Low church", in an Anglican context, denotes the church's simplicity or Protestant emphasis, and "high church" denotes an emphasis on ritual or, later, Anglo-Catholicism.

- [High Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_church)
- [Low church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_church)

Addition: The original story is generic enough to not refer to a particular church or even country: Some people discuss how a child should be brought up and it is mentioned that his religious upbringing should be "xxx church" rather than "yyy church". I understand that due to the peculiar nature of the term one *could* just reuse the English untranslated, but if at all possible I'd like a more native German term or phrase, as the original term would otherwise distract from the universality of the story. I could of course try for a list of attributes (as per the Wikipedia quote), but that is bound to make for a unwieldy construction...

Comment: It's hard to impossible to translate anything recreating connotations if the phenomenon does not exist in the target language. BTW "Low Church" article on WIkipedia has a link to German page which is called "Low Church".

Comment: Aparrently there is a "Hochkirchliche Beweung" https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hochkirchliche_Bewegung (_High Ecclesial Movement_ per Google's translation). This article states the opposite word as "Low Church": https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Church .

Comment: If it doesn't refer to the Anglican context, it may help to have some story-internal characterizations what kind of church or religious point of view these names are though to represent. *Hochkirche*, *Volkskirche*, *hohe Kirche*, *niedere Kirche* would be possible invented names, or more likely the different kind of churches could be named after some other kind of characteristic.

Comment: Thanks for the term and link, @user151841. I think it's close to the answer I was looking for - I'd be glad to accept if you would post it as an answer.

Comment: I just took some German in high school-- I have nowhere near enough background to know what would make sense to a native speaker. I only posted it as additional information. So I don't feel confident enough to post it as an answer, because I really don't know what it would mean to a native speaker :/

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty convinced the two denominations are too deeply intertwined with Anglican church history to have a direct counterpart in German.

German traditionally distinguishes between *katholisch* and *evangelisch* (protestants), the two main religious streams here, and "andere".

If you are looking into what could be called "level of orthodoxy" within these streams, you would maybe referring to *orthodoxe Katholiken* or *pietistische Protestanten* for persons that practice religion "by the book". That is the closest I can currently come up with, I think.

Comment: From the original piece, I came under the impression that it rather denoted (high church=) "formalistic, ritualistic, showy external display of religious tradition" versus (low church=) "sense of personal responsibility, inward conviction" - both leanings possible within the same (Church of England) denomination. I may be mistaken though.

Answer (score 1):

One could raise a child *streng/stramm/strikt gläubig/religiös/christlich/katholisch*, *erzkatholisch*, *(erz)konservativ* or *orthodox* which would somewhat resemble *High Church*, but I’ve trouble finding an antonym which would match *Low Church* because *locker/lose/lax* seem unidiomatic – maybe *weltlich/weltoffen*, *säkular* or just *liberal*.